# Delete files older than x while ignoring subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I've found several posts that are close to my question, but wanted to run it by you guys just to be 100% clear.
I have a folder: `B:/Backups` it has two subfolders `B:/Backups/Cust1` and `B:/Backups/Cust2`. `B:/Backups` also contains many `.bak` files.

I'd like to delete the `.bak` files older than X`` days from `B:/Backups` while completely ignoring those subfolders AND their contents.

I prefer a `batch file`/`robocopy` if possible.
Can anyone help me get started? Here is what I have tried:

```
forfiles /p b:/Backups\ /s /m *.bak /d -7 /c "cmd /c DEL @file"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us what code you've tried. Otherwise, it will appear that you want us to write your code for you and SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: forfiles /p b:/Backups\ /s /m *.bak /d -7 /c "cmd /c DEL @file"

Comment: I knew from reading I should have done that but I forgot in my original post. Sorry about that

Comment: Pleased edit your code into the question rather than the comment :)

Comment: the ` /s` says to do subfolders. Use `@Path` not `@fname`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
forfiles -p "b:\Backups\" -s -m *.bak /D 7 /C "cmd /c del @file"
```

This will delete .bak files older than 7 days in the specified folder, while completely ignoring subfolders.